# How can I make an if using 2 variables in Batch

Tags: batch-file, alarm

I have Windows 7 and I'm making a simple configurable Alarm clock but the User Input is hard to get right the way I'm going about it...

I need a variable one enters to be equal to %TIME%

```
set /p alarm="~ "
```

What I need is for this to work, or something along these lines

```
if %TIME%==%alarm% (

start C:\ALARM.mp3

)
```

Comment: What errors occur when you do what you just described?

Comment: why you dont use SCHTASKS or AT to schedule the alarm ?

Comment: Try `"%TIME%"=="%alarm%"`. You'd need to check this in a loop, though, and even then you'd be likely to miss `%TIME%` unless you restrict the values to hour and minute.

Answer (score 0):

do you need to compare 1/100 sec.? If not, try `if %time:~0,7%==%alarm% (`  Obvious both variables must have the same format.